# C# Sending Email with attached file (image)

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, email-attachments

My method sends an email using a SMTP Relay Server.

Everything works fine (the email gets sent), **except for that the attached file (the image) is somehow compressed/notexistent and not able to retrieve from the email.**

*The method looks like this:*

```
public static bool SendEmail(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage)
        {
            try
            {              
                var message = new MailMessage() //To/From address
                {
                    Subject = "This is subject."
                    Body = "This is text."
                };                             

                    if (uploadedImage != null && uploadedImage.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(uploadedImage.InputStream, uploadedImage.FileName);
                        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                //SMTP Credentials
                smtpClient.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //Logg exception
                return false;
            }
        }
```

1. The uploadedImage is not null.
2. ContentLength is 1038946 bytes (correct size).

**However, the email that is being sent contains the image as an attachment with correct filename, although it's size is 0 bytes.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of constructor of `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` is not the file name. It's the [content type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
And perhaps ensure your stream position is 0 before to create attachment

Answer (score 1):

@ChrisRun,

1. You should change the parameter HttpPostedFileBase as byte[] for example. This way you could re-use your class in more places.
2. Try changing FileName for ContentType and add the  MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg.
3. Also, add the using directive for dispose the MailMessage and SmtpClient

   ```
       using (var message = new MailMessage
       {
           From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com"),
           Subject = "This is subject.",
           Body = "This is text.",
           IsBodyHtml = true,
           To = { "to@someDomain.com" }
       })
       {
           if (imageFile != null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
           {
               message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imageFile.InputStream, imageFile.ContentType, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
           }

           using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
           {
               Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password"),
               EnableSsl = true
           })
           {
               client.Send(message);
           }
       }
   ```

Cheers

Comment: First: Thank you for your opinion.
Second: Did not work with the ContentType as parameter either.

Comment: @ChrisRun, I edited my previous answer with a working code. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: sorry, still doesn't work. The only solution I found was to first save the file on the server and then set the path to the physical location of that file.

Comment: Thats weird. it works for me, saving the file on the server not makes sense.